# TypeError in Gradient Boosting Regressor

Tags: python, anaconda, gradient-descent

**When i've done this part of code**

```
  from sklearn import ensemble
  clf = ensemble.GradientBoostingRegressor(n_estimators = 400, max_depth = 5, min_samples_split = 2, learning_rate = 0.1, loss = 'ls')
  clf.fit(x_train, y_train)
  clf.score(x_test,y_test)
  params = []
  t_sc = np.zeros((params['n_estimators']),dtype=np.float64)
```

i've

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

when execute this line.

```
t_sc = np.zeros((params['n_estimators']),dtype=np.float64)
```

need help.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SO. Please format your question properly to make it readable. Also read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I'm new here...I will improve next time .. Thanks for guidance :-)